Invitation to active users to ask a few more questions
The site's answer rate is currently sitting at around 85% and our questions per day is around 1.0.  One of the challenges of building this site is getting enough content so that we can start generating the social network and search traffic that can grow our user base.
Thus, I was wondering if any of our high or medium rep users would like to ask some more questions. I'm not talking about question seeding. Rather, I'm just suggesting those active on the site to ask a few more questions of interest:
E.g.,

You're reading a blog post or a journal article about psychology / cognitive science and you see something interesting, ask a question.
You're thinking about a research idea, and even if you think that you'll eventually work out the answer yourself, post a question. If you work it out later, just add an answer.

I think the medium to high rep users of our site should also be particularly suited to asking intelligent and answerable questions.
I'm trying to do this myself but could probably do it a little more.
Question

Does this sound like a good idea?
Is there some way of promoting this orientation? 
Could we have something like a "one question per day for a week challenge"?


Actually I cannot really see the difference between question seeding and your proposal.

I think the questions should be interesting (and not contrived). I'm also trying to encourage users (and myself) to recognise the little moments in the week (e.g., reading an article, thinking about an issue) where a question arises, and at that moment to think "I know. I'll post this on cogsci.SE.". And also to avoid thinking things like "I can work it out myself, I wont post". I guess I'm trying to encourage active users to incorporate asking questions more in to their workflow. It's that general open-science model of leaving an assortment of artefacts along the way.

Also, I hope my point is not disrespectful to those who prefer to answer but not ask. I know everyone appreciates people who provide good answers to questions. And if someone prefers to do just that, that's completely fine.

Of course you are not disrespectful. I can understand your reasoning but I just don't come to the same conclusion. Actually, encouraging not to think "I can work it out myself, I wont post" sounds a lot like encouraging to skip the initial research or to stop research although you are on the right track.

I suppose it could end up being an approach to avoid doing work. My emphasis would be on seeing an opportunity to build some knowledge on the Internet, part of which can involve coming back and answering your own question if needed.

SE doesn't particularly discourage you from asking questions you can eventually work out yourself. There's even a clause in the FAQ that states it's okay to ask and answer your own questions; while many think of it as a site about solving problems one person has it's really about sharing information, so that solving that problem for everyone. Just because with enough work you can solve it by yourself doesn't mean it's not a useful question to the Internet and our field at large.
